# To get likes of last month with Graph Api like "fanpagekarma" and "quintly" in FACEBOOK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fan-page

Is there a way to get the likes of last month using Graph API, of course, I am not admin, because being admin it is possible to get it. But using tools like fanpagekarma.com and quintly.com is possible! I don't know if it is possible. Thanks for all! :D

- Example of Fanpage Karma

[image: Example of Fanpage Karma]

- Example of Quintly

[image: Example of Quintly]

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: But, do you know how fanpagekarma work for to get data like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfjuE.png ?

Comment: Either they just get total number of likes and then request it every month. Or they scrape which is not allowed